# Configure Sonar to ignore single-line if-statements

Tags: java, sonarqube

Is there a way to configure Sonar to ignore single-line if-statements like

```
if (value == true) return;
```

while marking multi-line if-statements witout braces such as

```
if (value == true)
    return;
```

as violations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule that matches your needs but you can write your own rule with XPath. You can find a tutorial [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105194939/http://pmd.sourceforge.net:80/xpathruletutorial.html)

If you don't know how to extend the coding rules of sonar you can find a tutorial [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules)

Comment: I was totally for this, but how do I get XPath to recognize single line statements? When the code is in an AST, shouldn't the statements in question result in the same structure?

Answer (score 0):

SonarJava (default plugin for Java static analysis in SonarQube) provides [the rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-121) to always enforce curly braces for control flow structures.

However this will not allow single line if statements. You will need to create custom rule for that, with custom plugin. See [tutorial on writing custom rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101). You can use [implementation of SonarJava rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/cb1baeadb6f9beaab8a04a639a33b90944f73f19/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/MissingCurlyBracesCheck.java) as a guidance.